# SQL Query - Filtering out column values with None

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a PSQL database called raw and one of the columns is option, with type VARCHAR. The value is either 'Call', 'Put', or None.

I want to select all rows where the value of the option field is not 'Call' or 'Put', but rather None.

However, when I run this query:

```
curr.execute('SELECT * FROM holdings h WHERE option != \'Call\' AND option != \'Put\';')
```

nothing gets returned

If I run :

```
curr.execute('SELECT * FROM holdings h WHERE option != \'Call\';')
```

I only get those rows with option value = 'Put'

How can I get the rows with None for option, without just doing a set difference. Ideally I want to be able to just select those rows that aren't 'Call' and 'Put' without calling difference from the all the rows and those that have 'Call' and 'Put'

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Yes the actual field is None, when I was creating the database I put None as the default value if 'Put' and 'Call' were not the value

Comment: Should I put null as the value instead in the future?

Comment: Consider to use [`is distinct from`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from) instead of `!=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to select rows with `null` option, You must indicate this by `option IS NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM holdings WHERE option IS NULL
```

Instead of `option != 'Call' AND option != 'Put'` You can use `option NOT IN ('Call', 'Put')`:

```
SELECT * FROM holdings WHERE option NOT IN ('Call', 'Put')
```

And join this together with `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM holdings WHERE option NOT IN ('Call', 'Put') OR option IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM holdings h WHERE option =''
```